# Find the formula for the inverse of $y=\frac{1-\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}$

Tags: calculus

$$y=\frac{1-\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}$$

Here is my work. Let me know where I went wrong.

$$\begin{align}
x=\frac{1-\sqrt y}{1+\sqrt y}\implies x&=\frac{1-\sqrt y}{1+\sqrt y}\cdot1+\sqrt y\\[5pt]
\left(1+\sqrt y\right)x&=1-\sqrt y\\
\left(x+x\sqrt y\right)&=1-\sqrt y\\
\color{blue}{+\sqrt y}&\color{blue}{\quad\;+\sqrt y}\\[10pt]
x+2x\sqrt y&=1\\
\color{blue}{-x}\qquad&\quad\color{blue}{-x}\\[10pt]
\frac{2x\sqrt y}{2x}&=\frac{1-x}{2x}\\
\sqrt y&=\frac{1-x}{2x}\\
\left(\sqrt y\right)^2&=\left(\frac{1-x}{2x}\right)^2\\[5pt]
y&=\left(\frac{1-x}{2x}\right)^2\\[5pt]
F^{-1}(x)&=\left(\frac{1-x}{2x}\right)^2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in that $x+x\sqrt y=1-\sqrt y$, when you add $\sqrt y$ to both sides, it equals $x+x\sqrt y+\sqrt y=\sqrt y(x+1)+x$. You cannot combine $x\sqrt y$ and $\sqrt y$ into a single term.

Comment: How did you get $ \sqrt y(x+1)+x $ ?

Comment: $x\sqrt y+\sqrt y=x\sqrt y+1\cdot \sqrt y=(x+1)\sqrt y=\sqrt y(x+1)$

Comment: Can you do it from the point where I added the radicals. I still do not follow.

Comment: $$(1+\sqrt y)x=1-\sqrt y$$
$$x+x \sqrt y=1-\sqrt y$$
Add $\sqrt y$ to both sides
$$x+x\sqrt y +\sqrt y=1$$
Factor a $\sqrt y$
$$x+\sqrt y(x+1)=1$$
Subtract $x$
$$\sqrt y(x+1)=1-x$$
Divide $x+1$
$$\sqrt{y}=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$$
$$y=\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac x1=\dfrac{1-\sqrt y}{1+\sqrt y}$$

Applying  componendo and dividendo,  $$\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}=\sqrt y$$

Squaring 
$$y=\left(\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2$$

Comment: @SunnyBlack Componendo and dividendo is a technique to simplfy fractions. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo